# There are more and more linux process falling into 'D' status, server got stuck

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, locking, cpu

I am running a high performance application on Centos 7.4 op system 3.10 with RT kernel. Sometimes a few process falling into 'D' status(uninterruptible), such as systemd、runc init、umount. The stack of them is similar，and the first three levels are exactly same.

1. wait_rcu_gp+0x5e/0x80
2. synchronize_rcu.part.46+0x1f/0x40
3. synchronize_rcu+0x18/0x20
4. namespace_unlock+0x68/0x80
5. SyS_umount+0x25c/0440
6. system_call_fastpath+0x25/0x2a

The number of 'D' process is keep rising until the server got stuck. At that moment, ssh doesn't work，but ping is still working.

I did a little research about rcu，it's like a specific lock used by kernel. I use this cmd to search anything about rcu, "trace-cmd list -f|grep synchronize".
The result is

1. get_state_synchronize_rcu
2. synchronize_rcu_expedited
3. synchronize_rcu.part.46
4. synchronize_rcu
   It means the 'synchronize_rcu.part.46' is a specific function, but I can't find it in kernel code.

Does anyone was dealing with the same situation?

Comment: One common reason is disk failure, or network failure if any of your filesystems are over NFS.

Comment: No NFS service installed. My application requires fast response, so the priority of process was set pretty high, is that a relevant element?@PeterCordes

Comment: Not unless the priority was realtime, then maybe.  `nice -19` won't starve even user-space processes, and definitely not kernel stuff.  Anyway, this isn't a programming question about code, so it's off-topic for Stack Overflow.  It might be on-topic on https://serverfault.com/, https://superuser.com/, or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Appreciate it. I am totally new to this community. haha